# Replace Existing File with Temp File:I/O Error

Tags: command-line, batch-file, ftp, cmd, command

I have an Access 2007 database from which I call a Windows batch file to retrieve files from an external server via a ribbon menu. When executing the file manually everything works just fine. When executing the batch file via the Access ribbon menu the following error appears within the command line:

```
    Opening data connection for ...
    > Replace Existing File with Temp File:I/O Error
    Binary transfer complete.
```

I've read something about this error in relation to (Admin) rights, but since the batch file actually runs when called by Access it not seems to be the issue.

Comment: Is the file you're trying to replace the Access DB, or do you use it from the Access DB?

Comment: The .bat file is used to download .txt files via command line.

Comment: The .bat file is used to download .txt files via command line. When calling the .bat file via Access (from code OR ribbon menu) the error appears within cmd line and the files are not showing up in the expected directory. As said before, when executing the script manually (by clicking the .bat file itself) everything works fine.

Comment: without having seen the batch I can only say: shit happens.

Comment: Without seeing the batch wile we can only speculate.